# Determine the relative postion of a Chip to another one

Tags: microcontroller, rgb

For a project I want to have an unspecified amount of modules connected to each other. All of them will be controlled via a Controller. I would like to create a virtual map within the Controller, of the position of the modules relative to other ones. As you can the in the Image below, Chips 1-4 are connected  in a circle, which could obviously pose a problem, where signals are read multiple times and commands could run in a loop. Best case would be to get a X, Y Coordiante Map relative to the controller. (Chip1 = 0|1, Chip3 = 1|1 and so on...)

All of this will be done to mimic Nanoleaf RGB panels ([Website](https://nanoleaf.me/en-EU/) and a [Teardown](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/nanoleaf-aurora-teardown/)), that create a Virtual Map of the Panels to play lighting scenes. I just can't figure out how I would be able to create such map and the teardown didn't went deep enough into that or I atleast was unable to understand it, but they made some findings like:

> For the topology discovery, they use the EDGE pin. While VBUS is UART half-duplex broadcast, EDGE is a simple level signal, purely point-to-point used only doing discovery. As they walk down the tree structure to discover it, they basically turn on one EDGE pin on an unexplored branch of the tree, then through the VBUS ask whichever tile is seeing EDGE=1 to respond. From that, they get a unique tile ID (factory programmed I believe), then use this to assign a short ID to that tile, so they can talk to it later. Then they keep going.

But I wasn't able to make anything out of that, because my technical understanding of such circuits isn't too great.

*My modules will be hexagonal (6 Ports) but this should work similar.*
[image: Multiple chips with four in and outputs each, some of the ports are connected to other chips, others not.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as though it works something like this:

- Controller turns on it's EDGE pin and then broadcasts a message out from it's UART saying 'whoever can see an incoming EDGE signal, respond to me' - and CHIP1 responds. It's response probably indicates that it's seeing EDGE on its Port 1.
- Controller then disables its own EDGE pin and tells CHIP1 to turn on its EDGE pin on its Port 2, then broadcasts another 'whoever can see an incoming EDGE signal, respond to me' - and CHIP5 responds. It's response probably indicates that it's seeing EDGE on its Port 4.
- Then, depending on the preference of the designer, Controller could either tell CHIP5 to enable EDGE on its Port1, send a broadcast, get no response, tell CHIP5 to enable EDGE on its port1, get no response, etc...
- Or it could instead go back to CHIP1 and tell it to enable EDGE on its Port3, send a broadcast, and get a response from CHIP2, etc
- and then continue on throughout the matrix of devices until it's enabled EDGE on each port of each CHIP it discovers and knows that it's discovered the entire matrix.

About 8 years ago I did something similar - my bus was 1Mbit RS485 (although discovery took place at a much slower baud rate), and instead of an extra 'EDGE' pin I had a bus switch on each port which I could selectively enable and disable until I had discovered the matrix of devices.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot. Is there any type of chip you can recommend for doing such thing?